# Why Response.Cookies is empty?

Tags: c#, cookies, web

When I run this python script

```
import requests

main_page_request = requests.get("http://carkit.kg/")
cookie = main_page_request.cookies.get("csrftoken", "")
```

I'm getting proper result, but when I run this code at C#:

```
string url = @"http://carkit.kg";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Debug.Log(response.Cookies["csrftoken"]); // prints "Null"
```

it says that response.Cookies is empty. What is the problem?

Comment: `response.Cookies['mycookie'])` won't compile. Care to show your actual code?

Comment: In python you are reading cookies from request and in C# from response.

Comment: code updated. When I try to use request.Cookies - it says: 'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Cookies'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a cookie container to the request. Then it returns the cookie:

```
CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = c;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine(response.Cookies["csrftoken"]);
// prints "csrftoken=E1iRIi7cQvxvJcnSgOgaEP3XPxTHRUfT"
```